# Cycles baking taking VERY long

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I'm in 2.8 beta, and I have made a 1024x1024 texture, and I am trying to bake onto it with 128 samples. For whatever reason it used to only take about 2 minutes to bake a 4096x4096 texture, but at one point for seemingly no reason it takes an hour on just a 1024x1024 texture. What should I fix?

[.blend file](https://mega.nz/#!n5wG1CwJ!IbPVLDx_IXKgF7_xPQqZY_6t3XuboRIyhdcIJDVbz-M)